# targets::tar_map() example? (R targets static branching)

Tags: r, target, targets-r-package

Does anyone have an example of how to use static branching from the targets package (R)?
I'm reading targets manual on static branching but I'm having a hard time understanding it (even though I do get dynamic branching).

https://books.ropensci.org/targets/static.html

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example `_targets.R` very similar to a project I have:

```
library(targets)
library(tarchetypes)
library(dplyr)

params <- tribble(
  ~name, ~arg1,  ~arg2,  
  "A",  "a",  1,    
  "B",  "b",  2,
  "C",  "c",  3  
) 

mapped_pipeline <- tar_map(
  values = params, 
  names = "name",
  tar_target(first_target,
             f(arg1, arg2)),
  tar_target(second_target,
             g(first_target)
  )
)

tar_pipeline(pipeline)
```

And the pipeline looks something like this:
[image]